# how to use latest jaxb with default value pugin and jdk 1.6

Tags: jaxb, java-6

Since jdk 1.6, the jaxb-xjc related jars are included and automatically loaded by the JVM when using the **java** command. I am currently trying to use the xjc default value plugin in the following manner:

```
java -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\workspace\javalibs\xjc -classpath C:\apache-ant-1.8.3\lib\ant.jar;c:\workspace\javalibs\xjc\cxf-xjc-dv-2.6.1.jar com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCFacade -d test -extension -Xdv -verbose test.xsd
```

The `java.endorsed.dirs` property is supposed to allow you to override the jdk version of jaxb with a later complete version. The version used in jdk 1.6 is **2.1.10**. I therefore put the jaxb **2.2** related jars in the endorsed dirs directory. In spite of that I get the following error when executing the **java** command:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation:
loader (instance of <bootloader>) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "com/sun/tools/xjc/outline/Outline"
    at org.apache.cxf.xjc.dv.DefaultValuePlugin.run(DefaultValuePlugin.java:105)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.addon.apache_cxf.dv.DefaultValuePlugin.run(DefaultValuePlugin.java:59)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.model.Model.generateCode(Model.java:290)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver.run(Driver.java:343)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver.run(Driver.java:191)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver._main(Driver.java:116)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver.access$000(Driver.java:74)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver$1.run(Driver.java:96)
```

I then tested the plugin with jdk 1.5, and the classes are generated by xjc correctly, without hitch. The reason for this is jdk 1.5 doesn't include the jaxb-xjc related jars, so they weren't pre-loaded, and hence, there was no Linkage error clash. My question is how can I get jdk 1.6 to use the jaxb jars I provide (either by `java.endorsed.dirs` or some other manner), and not the pre-packaged ones, so that I can correctly use the plugin?